# JQuery animate to "Height: 0px;" is still showing

Tags: jquery

I have recently tried to implement my drop-down menu to work upon clicking on my button to animate from "Height: 0px;" to "Height: 260px;", however, upon loading of the document, the div is visible even though overflow is set to be hidden and the height is set as 0px.

```
$('.DropBtn a').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("href") == "#Open") {
        $(this).attr("href", "#Close");
        $('#Font-Size .DropList').stop().animate({
            height: "260px",
        }, 400);
    } else if ($(this).attr("href") == "#Close") {
        $(this).attr("href", "#Open");
        $('#Font-Size .DropList').stop().animate({
            height: "0px",
        }, 400);
    }
});
```

Above is the recent addition to my script and you can view it live on JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/anw4B/).

Thank you for any help provided for a solution to my problems,

Best Regards,

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `height` to 0 does not hide the element. It still has `margin` and `padding` which cause it to be displayed. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/anw4B/1/

```
else if ($(this).attr("href") == "#Close") {
        $(this).attr("href", "#Open");
        $('#Font-Size .DropList').stop().animate({
            height: "0px",
        }, 400, function() {$('#Font-Size .DropList').hide()});
    }
```

I believe this is better than changing the `margin` and the `padding` because it allows you to regularly use the CSS. Also note, that there are two more changes in the fiddle (showing the list before expanding it and hiding it by default in the CSS).

Answer (score 0):

It is visible because of the `padding` and the `border` properties.

<kbd>[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anw4B/3/)</kbd>

In this fiddle I animate the `padding` along with the `height` and have a `callback` function after the animation is over to remove the `border` property. I do this just for the sake of demonstrating to you where the problem is, if I were you, I'd rather have a callback function that hides the element at the end of the animation, and shows it before the animations runs.

<kbd>[Edited fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anw4B/4/)</kbd>

```
// This is how the line to show the list would look like.
// Note the .show() before .animate(). 
$('#Font-Size .DropList').stop().show().animate({
    height: "260px",
}, 400);

// That's for hiding. Note the callback function that hides
// the element at the end of the animation
$('#Font-Size .DropList').stop().animate({
     height: "0px",
}, 400,
function () { $(this).hide() });
```

Technically this will make the element disappear when it reaches `height: 0` but it has still `3px` of padding and `2px` of border; but in my opinion this is unnoticeable. Try it yourself.